# unit test react container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon-chai

I am trying to unit test React container component using chai/sinon. This is how the component is defined:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { loadData } = this.props;
    loadData();
  }

  render() {
    const { links, heading } = this.props;
    return (
      <p>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
        <div>{links.map(link => link.label)}</div>
      </p>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  heading: state.heading,
  links: state.links
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  loadData: dispatch('LOAD_DATA')
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestComponent);
```

I am writing a unit test to assert that container component has the props `loadData, heading` and `links`. Below is the unit test:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import TestContainer from './TestContainer';

const mockStore = configureStore({});

describe('TestContainer', () => {
  const initialState = {
    heading: 'A test component',
    links: []
  };
  const store = mockStore(initialState);
  it(
    'renders correctly',
    sinon.test(() => {
      const component = shallow(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <TestContainer />
        </Provider>
      );
      console.log(component.prop('heading')); // prints undefined

      expect(component.prop('heading')).to.equal('A test component'); // gives AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'A test component'
    })
  );
});
```

Above unit test fails and I get all props as undefined. Can somebody explain what am I doing wrong OR how a container component props should be asserted?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try console.log(component.props().heading)

Comment: it seems you are mixing up testing suites. Why not to use Jest assertions which are provided out of the box?

Comment: @VipinYadav component.props().heading) is also undefined

Comment: @Rostyslav, can we not test a react container using Chai. Even if I remove sinon from here I get same result.

Comment: @reactdesign the problem is that your `component` returned by shallow is `Provider` and not `TestComponent`. And `Provider` does not have any props.

Comment: @Rostylav, you were right. I changed ```shallow``` to ```mount``` and this works ```    expect(
      component
        .find(TestContainer)
        .find('TestComponent')
        .prop('heading')
    ).to.equal('A test component');```

Comment: However it would interesting to find if its possible to continue use ```shallow``` if I don't want to set all the mocks for all child components.